# PHP - does a destructor have access to any methods or properties

Tags: php

In php when using the destructor, does the code inside the destructor still have access to any methods and properties of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access both methods and properties within a destructor, as demonstrated by [this simple test-case](http://viper-7.com/DYHbuO):

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = 'member variable - ';
    function bar() {
        return 'function';
    }
    function __destruct() {
        echo $this->bar;
        echo $this->bar();
    }
}
$o = new Foo;
unset( $o);
```

Which prints:

> member variable - function

See the [PHP Docs on for deconstructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more information, including their example of referencing a member variable from within the destructor.

Comment: +1 for the example. The documentation on [Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) confirms this as well.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks for the link, figured I would try it first before checking the docs. I'll update my answer to include it.